# Differences Between Array Indexing With Colons and Without

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm pretty new to python and am doing some basic level data analysis when I came across this issue. I'm pulling data from a .csv file and finding the average of some values. Basically, I see a difference between adding colons and indexing from my numpy array, and when I just call for different entries.

I would like to have just numerical values so that I can use the average values to plot a scatterplot.

Below is my code:

```
mean = []
data = pd.read_csv(file)

data_edit = data.filter(['MSCV-iRFP-A']) 
mean.append(np.mean(data_edit))
mean.append(format(file))
from numpy  import array
mean_array = array(mean)
mean_values = array([mean_array[0], mean_array[2], mean_array[4]])
mean_values_2 = array([mean_array[0:6:2]])
print(mean_values)
print(mean_values_2)
```

The output for mean_values is

```
[[495.35978305]
 [411.64597191]
 [461.34993978]]
```

Which is what I am expecting (and need for plotting my data as a scatterplot).

However, the output for mean_values_2 is:

```
[[MSCV-iRFP-A    495.359783
dtype: float64
  MSCV-iRFP-A    411.645972
dtype: float64
  MSCV-iRFP-A    461.34994
dtype: float64]]
```

Why are both of these different? I'm assuming they're doing the same thing, but I'm unsure why there's such a drastic difference.

Thanks!

Comment: `mean_values` looks like a (3,1) array of numbers (floats).  `mean_values_2` looks like a (3,1) array of 'objects`, where the objects are `pandas.Series`.  `data` is a pandas `DataFrame`.  Pay attention to what each action produces - when is it a DataFrame, when a Series, when a list, an array of numbers, array of Series, etc.